# which testframework for Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: selenium, ant, selenium-webdriver

I know there are some other questions on this topic in stackoverflow. But I am looking for a specific answer- 
IF I used JUnit, then the data cannot be shared between tests present in different classes. 
e.g. a static variable counter initialized to zero. I am printing its value in the `@Test` method. Then doing the same in another `@Test` in second class. I am invoking both the Tests in these two classes via a `build.xml`  like this

```
<target name="LoginTestAndPreReqs" depends="dist">
    <mkdir dir="${java.test.reports.path}" />
    <junit haltonfailure="no" printsummary="true">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location = "${build}" />
        </classpath>
    <formatter type="xml"/>
        <batchtest fork="yes" todir="${java.test.reports.path}">
            <fileset dir="${build}/">
                <include name="**/TestUnits.class"/>
                <include name="**/TestUnits1.class"/>
                <exclude name="**/*$*.class"/>
            </fileset>
        </batchtest>
    </junit>
</target>
```

But the output shows the counter is reset to zero for each TestUnit* method. It means the counter incremented in not shared between these two tests.

Now, for `selenium` I am using the `webdriver` APIs.I want to maintain the driver object that I used to login to my site. How can I pass this driver object between different `@Test` method when they are present in different classes ? With `Junit` this seems not possible. Or perhaps I may be doing something wrong in the `build.xml`. It seems that each test case is invoked in a different `JVM`.

Answer (score 0):

When I used Junit and Webdriver I wrote any values to be used in later tests to a text file. Later tests would then read to file to get the values required.

I used this method to pass a booking reference generated in one test to another test requiring a certain booking type.